# Displaying decimal numbers in Windows Phone virtual keyboard

Tags: windows-phone-7

I have a TextBox placed on the main page in a Windows Phone application. Once I tap it, a virtual keyboard is displayed by the OS. Is there a way to display decimal numbers once the keyboard comes up? This action would be equivalent to tapping &123 at the bottom left corner of the keyboard. The TextBox should accept only numbers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your XAML code, change the input scope. 
For example:

```
<TextBox x:Name="expense" Margin="0,61,252,16" Text="Expense">
            <TextBox.InputScope>
                <InputScope>
                    <InputScopeName NameValue="Digits" />
                </InputScope>
            </TextBox.InputScope>
</TextBox>
```

Comment: In case you wish to know a little more on input scope, this link might help you better: http://www.imaginativeuniversal.com/blog/post/2010/07/06/wp7-inputscope.aspx

Comment: You'll still want to validate the entered text, as it's still possible to paste non-numeric text into the TextBox regardless of the InputScope.

Comment: @PrashantVaidyanathan Out of interest, why have you written the attribute like that? Simply setting the attribute `InputScope` within the `TextBox` tag works the same and is cleaner. `<TextBox x:Name="expense" Margin="0,61,252,16" Text="Expense" InputScope="Digits">`

Comment: @user1763532 You are right. You can simply add the attribute InputScope within the TextBox as a shorter syntax. However, I was using Blend 4 back then and it marks the code as invalid, although it compiles the code without any issues.
Also, I thought it would be more helpful to explain the hierarchy of the attribute using the longer syntax